# Laravel giving me Array to string conversion error, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, string, laravel, object

Im using Laravel 5.3 on ubuntu 16.04, when I run this code:

```
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($currentSessions[0]);
    echo "</pre>";

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($lmirOrder);
    echo "</pre>";
```

These are returned:

$currentSessions[0] is:

```
stdClass Object
(
[iID] => 484444768
[bStatus] => SESSION_ONHOLDBUTCUSTOMERLEFT
[sStatus] => Closed by waiting customer
[iEntry] => 404466296
[sEntry] => Technical Support
[iTechnician] => 17536581
[sTechnician] => Removed
[sStartTime] => 11/23/2016 2:48:35 PM
[iWaitingTimeInSec] => 2 Hours
[sCustomField0] => removed
[sCustomField1] => removed
[sCustomField2] => Array
    (
        [phoneNumber] => removed
        [emailAddress] => removed
    )

[sCustomField3] => 
[sCustomField4] => 
[sCustomField5] => 
[sLanguage] => en
[sTransferredTo] => 
[sTransferredComment] => 
[bIsLead] => 1
[bHandingOff] => 
)
```

$lmirOrder is:

```
Array
(
[1] => sTechnician
[2] => sCustomField0
[3] => sCustomField2[phoneNumber]
[4] => sStatus
[5] => sStartTime
[6] => sCustomField1
[7] => iWaitingTimeInSec
[8] => sCustomField2[emailAddress]
)
```

Why do I get "Array to string conversion" error when I echo:

```
echo $currentSessions[0]->$lmirOrder[4];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is what PHP does: `echo {$currentSessions[0]->$lmirOrder}[2];` and now think what type `$lmirOrder` is, which is used as property name.

Comment: @Rizier123 I was unaware of that, that makes complete sense though. Anyway I can get around this?

Comment: How did you get to form this array `$currentSessions[0]`?

Comment: You could probably just do `echo $currentSessions[0]->{$lmirOrder[4]};`

Comment: See the manual for this behaviour: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php and a bit nicer table: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling which also shows how it is different in PHP 7.

Comment: @JoelHinz that worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Of course. After he said that to me, it clicked, thanks for the help as well @Rizier123!

Comment: @JoeyStout Also note that if you have a long code line and you don't know where the error is you can just break it up and see on which line the error is. E.g. `echo $currentSessions[0]` Line break `->$lmirOrder[4];`

Comment: Added the comment from @Rizier123 as a community wiki answer following guidelines at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/283844.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the statement `$currentSessions[0]->$lmirOrder[4]` actually being interpreted as `{$currentSessions[0]->$lmirOrder}[4]` causing the property `Array` to be looked up on the object.

```
<?php

$a = new stdClass();
$a->test = 'Hello World';
$a->Array = "You didn't want me";

$b = ['test'];

// Notice: Array to string conversion in php shell code on line 6
// string(1) "Y"
var_dump($a->$b[0]); 

// string(11) "Hello World"
var_dump($a->{$b[0]});
```